# What is the average time it takes before a question is answered?

Tags: feature-request, statistics

How long is the average wait time to have a question answered? I know that most people have lives outside of this forum so I know people may not have time to skim through the current unanswered questions.

There are several questions I have seen that have not been answered in several years.  This person's question hasn't been answered in 2 1/2 years.

[image]

Comment: See [Distribution of time to first answer in MathStackExchange?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/12131) which is a bit dated (December 2013).

Comment: Here's an unanswered question from February, 2011: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24025/are-the-correspondences-between-value-groups-and-field-extensions-order-preservi

Comment: Instead of "average", why not ask for "median"?  Then it won't be made undefined by unanswered questions.

Comment: @Gerry: At least having lots of comments prevents it from automatic deletion.

Comment: It seems that the [oldest](http://math.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?page=1703&tab=newest) unanswered question is this one: [An elegant description for graded-module morphisms with non-zero zero component](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730/an-elegant-description-for-graded-module-morphisms-with-non-zero-zero-component), from July 2010.

Comment: So, according to pizza's link: the median time to answer is 23 minutes.  That is as of 2 years ago.  And only answered questions are counted.

Comment: The distribution of time post is quite antiquated in its information.  I want average not median because the median is extremely undescriptive of a set.  Ex. 1 (1,1,1,5,10) median is 1 and average is 3.6. quite a diferrence.  I have a hard time believe it is 23 minutes.

Comment: @Aethelred the average is exactly as undescriptive as the median, for example the set $S=\{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,10^{132}\}$ has average $(10^{132}+9)/10 \approx 10^{131}$. Having the average **and** the median is interesting (in particular because you can compare them).

Comment: If at least one question has no answer (ever), then the mean time for answers is infinite.